# If $2^x=9$ and $4^y=27$ then what will $\frac {x+2y}{2y-4x}$ be?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

If $2^x=9$ and $4^y=27$ then what will $\frac {x+2y}{2y-4x}$ be?

I have seen such problems many times but no specific method to solve them.

I hope I find the general rule to solve them here.

Comment: What does $y$ represent?

Comment: $2^x = 9\implies x = \frac{\ln(9)}{\ln(2)}$

Comment: nice comment regret. I edited

Comment: similarly to what Surb did: $4^y = 27 \Rightarrow y=\frac{\ln\left(27\right)}{\ln\left(4\right)}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

since
$$2^{x+2y}=2^x\cdot 4^y=9\cdot 27=3^5$$
and note
$$2^{2y-4x}=4^y/(2^x)^4=27/9^4=3^{-5}$$
so
$$2^{x+2y}\cdot 2^{2y-4x}=2^{(x+2y)+(2y-4x)}=3^5\cdot 3^{-5}=1=2^{0}$$
so $$\Longrightarrow x+2y+2y-4x=0$$
$$\Longrightarrow  x+2y=-(2y-4x)$$
so
$$\Longrightarrow  \dfrac{x+2y}{2y-4x}=-1$$

Comment: nicely elegant :)!

Comment: better answer is the simpler.

Answer (score 3):

We have $$2^x = 9\implies x\ln(2)=\ln(2^x)=\ln(9)\implies x = \frac{\ln(9)}{\ln(2)}= 2 \frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(2)}$$
and 
$$4^y = 27\implies y = \frac{\ln(27)}{\ln(4)}= \frac{3}{2}\frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(2)}$$

So

$$\frac {x+2y}{2y-4x} =\frac {2 \frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(2)}+3\frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(2)}}{3\frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(2)}-8\frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(2)}} =-1$$

Comment: it'll be better if you answer the question using this method

Comment: there isn't much left to answer @BlueSky. Just plug in the values.

Comment: I haven't seen the function In() up to now! I am not that professional in math. Isn't there any other ways expect using In() ?

Comment: You can use the log of any base if that helps, your calculator has base e (ln) and 10 (log) tho :)

Comment: @BlueSky I completed my answer

Comment: and it\s done. thanks.

Comment: @BlueSky Have a look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm

Comment: @surb. I got a better article : http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/logarithms.html :D

Answer (score 1):

I think a natural is to eliminate $2,3$(bases)

$$2^x=9=3^2$$

$$27=4^y=(2^2)^y\iff3^3=2^{2y}$$

$$\implies(2^x)^3=(2^{2y})^2\iff2^{3x}=2^{4y}$$

As $2\ne0,\pm1;3x=4y$

Comment: @BlueSky, How about this?